# Looking for an elegant proof of why there is only ever a single intersection point of the nullclines for a 2D ODE system

Tags: number-theory, ordinary-differential-equations, intersection-theory

I have the following ODE system
$$
\dfrac{d \ell}{dt}=\sigma_{\ell} - \mu_{\ell} \dfrac{M \ell}{1+\ell}-d_{\ell}\ell \\
\dfrac{dM}{dt}=\dfrac{\ell}{\beta+\ell}+\sigma_M \dfrac{M \ell}{1+\ell}-M
$$
where both the variables $\ell$ and $M$ and parameters $\sigma_{\ell}$, $\mu_{\ell}$, $d_{\ell}$, $\sigma_M$ and $\beta$ are all positive reals.

Is there someway to show that the nullclines of this system (i.e. when the left hand side of the above 2 equations equals zero) intersect exactly once for all $\ell$, $M$ $\in \mathbb{R}^+$ and for all $\sigma_{\ell}$, $\mu_{\ell}$, $d_{\ell}$, $\sigma_M$, $\beta$ $\in \mathbb{R}^+$.

ps I don't mind if you set $\beta=1$. It isn't really that important to my model.

Comment: do you have any reason to believe that there is only one equilibrium for general $l\ \textrm{and}\ M$? I don't think that this is true.

Comment: @okrzysik I have computed hundreds of different plots for a wide variety of parameter values and my PhD supervisor is certain of it. However I cannot say that it is definitely the case. I would be equally happy to see a proof that this is not that case i.e. that there is more than one intersection of the nullclines.

Comment: It's just that after playing around with it for a couple of minutes I found two quadratics that $l$ must satisfy. And $l$ has to be real solutions to these quadratics, so there must be zero, 2 or 4 values of $l$ at which there are equilibria.

Comment: @okrzysik I understand but can you find any solutions to these quadratics such that all the parameters are real and positive and that more than one solution of $(l,M)$ is in the first quadrant?

Comment: I don't know what solutions exist for the given parameters; I haven't tried to solve the equations. I'm just saying there has to be (p.v. I didn't make a mistake in deriving the quadratics) 0, 2, or 4 equilibria in $l$. i.e. there cannot be only 1 as you suggest. As to which quadrant of the $(l,M)$ phase plane these equilibria lie in; I am unsure.

Comment: on second thoughts, I'm not so sure. I think I've just gone and confused myself... Sorry.

Comment: Why do you avoid solving such systems with pen and paper? Everything again leads to quadratic equation in $l$ which is tractable.

Comment: @Evgeny I have certainly tried. Actually with this model you get a cubic equation in $l$ upon simplifying and the coefficients are certainly complicated enough to warrant this question. If it is so easy please provide a complete solution.

Comment: Okay, sorry, my bad. Have you tried methods that allow you to tell how many real roots do you have in given interval?

Comment: I haven't. If you have the time, could you point me in the right direction? I have never attempted anything like that method you mentioned.

Comment: @Evgeny I actually figured it out by taking the derivative of the nullclines and proving that they are monotonic.

Comment: Oh, that's great!